# write a function and return all the values within the function for enumerate

Tags: python

I would like my function to return all the indices and values for the loop:

Code:

```
a = [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"]]

def count(a):
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        return i,x
aa = count(a)
print(aa)
```

Output:

```
(0, ['one'])
```

Expected output:

```
(0 ['one'])
(1 ['two'])
(2 ['three'])
(3 ['four'])
```

Comment: You are probably searching for `yield`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting the first item because you return the first time you loop. Try something like this. Modify it as you need.

```
a = [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"]]

def count(a):
    output_str = ""
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        output_str += str(i) + "," + str(x) + "\n"
    return output_str

aa = count(a)
print(aa)
```

**Output**

```
0,['one']                                                                                                                                                                          
1,['two']                                                                                                                                                                          
2,['three']                                                                                                                                                                        
3,['four']
```

As @C. Yduqoli suggested, this can be done with `yield`. But would involve an additional step, like so:

```
a = [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"]]

def count(a):
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        yield i,x

aa = count(a)
for item in aa:
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
(0, ['one'])                                                                                                                                                                       
(1, ['two'])                                                                                                                                                                       
(2, ['three'])                                                                                                                                                                     
(3, ['four'])
```

Comment: Thanks sir but I guess yield will be shorter since I have multiple functions to make. Thank you again

Comment: @Beginner see edited answer for an example with yield as well

Answer (score 0):

Since `enumerate()` returns an `iterable`, not a `sequence`, in your case, you can turn it into a `sequence` by `list()` or `tuple()`.

```
a = [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"]]

def count(a):
    return list(enumerate(a))

aa = count(a)
print(aa)
```

Note that the output of the above code is not exactly what you will expect, since we are printing a `list` here.